# In my assembly program, I am trying to calculate the equation of (((((2^0 + 2^1) * 2^2) + 2^3) * 2^4) + 2^5)

Tags: math, assembly, x86

In my 80x86 assembly program, I am trying to calculate the equation of 
(((((2^0 + 2^1) * 2^2) + 2^3) * 2^4) + 2^5)...(2^n), where each even exponent is preceded by a multiplication and each odd exponent is preceded by a plus. I have code, but my result is continuously off from the desired result. When 5 is put in for n, the result should be 354, however I get 330.

Any and all advice will be appreciated.

```
.586
.model flat

include io.h

.stack 4096

.data
number dword ?
prompt byte "enter the power", 0
string byte 40 dup (?), 0
result byte 11 dup (?), 0
lbl_msg byte "answer", 0
bool dword ?
runtot dword ?

.code
_MainProc proc
    input prompt, string, 40
    atod string
    push eax


    call power



    add esp, 4

    dtoa result, eax
    output lbl_msg, result

    mov eax, 0
    ret

_MainProc endp

power proc
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    push ecx

    mov bool, 1     ;initial boolean value
    mov eax, 1
    mov runtot, 2   ;to keep a running total
    mov ecx, [ebp + 8]

    jecxz done

loop1:
    add eax, eax        ;power of 2
    test bool, ecx      ;test case for whether exp is odd/even
    jnz oddexp          ;if boolean is 1
    add runtot, eax     ;if boolean is 0
    loop loop1

oddexp:
    mov ebx, eax        ;move eax to seperate register for multiplication
    mov eax, runtot     ;move existing total for multiplication
    mul ebx             ;multiplication of old eax to new eax/running total
    loop loop1

done:
    mov eax, runtot     ;move final runtotal for print
    pop ecx
    pop ebp
    ret




power endp



end
```

Comment: Your code falls through into `oddexp`. You need a `jmp done` just before `oddexp:`. You might have other problems too. Learn to use a debugger.

Comment: The code automatically jumps to done once ECX is at 0. The debugger has been used thoroughly.

Comment: Yeah I suppose that's true since `ecx` can only reach zero from one and that's odd. If you can use the debugger, then simply single step the code for `n=1` or whichever is the smallest value it produces wrong result) and see why. PS: I don't see you writing back into `runtot` after the `mul ebx` and that also happens to destroy `eax` which you use to keep track of the power of two. Is that intended? Even if it is, that puts result into `eax` but you reload if from `runtot` in `done`.

Comment: Using the code I provided, when n = 1, the result is 2. The result should be 3, and when the code is ran the result is 330. I feel like there is a factor off somewhere, but don't exactly know where I should add or adjust it.

Comment: The result is `2` for `n=1` because that goes directly to `oddexp` which then calculates the result in `eax` but that is subsequently overwritten by the value in `runtot` which is `2`. Single stepping in a debugger should have showed you that. See the PS section in my previous comment.

Comment: Okay, I did notice that, but didn't make the connection to what was happening. Thank you. Is there any advice to work through that?

Comment: I am not sure I follow your intended algorithm correctly but as I said, I would make sure `eax` is preserved if you want to keep the powers of two in there, and write the result of the multiplication back into `runtot`.

Comment: These are powers of 2, you could (and should) just left-shift by 1.  (Or for multiply by 2^n, left-shift by a count in `cl`, so count `cl` up towards `n`).  I also don't see the point of having a static variable called `bool` which you seem to only use as an operand for `test`.  You're just making your code more complicated and harder to read vs. writing `test ecx,1` to check the low bit for zero / non-zero.  You also don't need static storage for `runtot`, just use a register.  32-bit x86 has 7 registers (not including the stack pointer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're overcomplicating your code with static variables and branching.

These are powers of 2, you can (and should) just left-shift by `n` instead of actually constructing `2^n` and using a `mul` instruction.

`add eax,eax` is the best way to multiply by 2 (aka left shift by 1), but it's not clear why you're doing that to the value in EAX at that point.  It's either the multiply result (which you probably should have stored back into `runtot` after `mul`), or it's that left-shifted by 1 after an even iteration.

If you were trying to make a `2^i` variable (with a strength reduction optimization to shift by 1 every iteration instead of shifting by `i`), then your bug is that you clobber EAX with `mul`, and its setup, in the `oddexp` block.

As Jester points out, if the first `loop loop1` falls through, it will fall through into `oddexp:`.  When you're doing loop tail duplication, make sure you consider where fall-through will go from each tail if the loop does end there.

---

There's also no point in having a static variable called `bool` which holds a `1`, which you only use as an operand for `test`.  That implies to human readers that the mask sometimes needs to change; `test ecx,1` is a lot clearer as a way to check the low bit for zero / non-zero.

You also don't need static storage for `runtot`, just use a register (like EAX where you want the result eventually anyway).  32-bit x86 has 7 registers (not including the stack pointer).

---

This is how I'd do it.  Untested, but I simplified a lot by unrolling by 2.  Then the test for odd/even goes away because that alternating pattern is hard-coded into the loop structure.

We increment and compare/branch twice in the loop, so unrolling didn't get rid of the loop overhead, just changed one of the loop branches into an an `if() break` that can leave the loop from the middle.

This is *not* the most efficient way to write this; the increment and early-exit check in the middle of the loop could be optimized away by counting another counter down from `n`, and leaving the loop if there are less than 2 steps left.  (Then sort it out in the epilogue)

```
;; UNTESTED
power proc   ; fastcall calling convention: arg: ECX = unsigned int n
             ; clobbers: ECX, EDX
             ; returns: EAX

    push  ebx           ; save a call-preserved register for scratch space

    mov   eax, 1        ; EAX = 2^0   running total / return value
    test  ecx,ecx
    jz    done

    mov   edx, ecx      ; EDX = n
    mov   ecx, 1        ; ECX = i=1..n loop counter and shift count

loop1:                  ; do{   // unrolled by 2
    ; add 2^odd power
    mov   ebx, 1
    shl   ebx, cl         ; 2^i         ; xor   ebx, ebx; bts   ebx, ecx
    add   eax, ebx        ; total += 2^i

    inc   ecx
    cmp   ecx, edx
    jae   done            ; if (++i >= n) break;

    ; multiply by 2^even power
    shl   eax, cl       ; total <<= i;  // same as total *= (1<<i)

    inc   ecx           ; ++i
    cmp   ecx, edx
    jb    loop1         ; }while(i<n);

done:
    pop  ebx
    ret
```

I didn't check if the adding-odd-power step ever produces a carry into another bit.  I think it doesn't, so it could be safe to implement it as `bts eax, ecx` (setting bit `i`).  Effectively an OR instead of an ADD, but those are equivalent as long as the bit was previously cleared.

To make the asm look more like the source and avoid obscure instructions, I implemented `1<<i` with `shl` to generate `2^i` for `total += 2^i`, instead of a more-efficient-on-Intel `xor ebx,ebx` / `bts ebx, ecx`.  (Variable-count shifts are 3 uops on Intel Sandybridge-family because of x86 flag-handling legacy baggage: flags have to be untouched if count=0).  But that's worse on AMD Ryzen, where `bts reg,reg` is 2 uops but `shl reg,cl` is 1.

---

**Update: `i=3` *does* produce a carry when adding, so we can't OR or BTS the bit for that case.  But optimizations are possible with more branching.**

[Using `calc`](http://www.isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/calc/):

```
; define shiftadd_power(n) { local res=1; local i; for(i=1;i<=n;i++){ res+=1<<i; i++; if(i>n)break; res<<=i;} return res;}
shiftadd_power(n) defined
; base2(2)

; shiftadd_power(0)
        1 /* 1 */
...
```

The first few outputs are:

```
n          shiftadd(n) (base2)

0                   1
1                  11
2                1100
3               10100     ; 1100 + 1000 carries
4           101000000
5           101100000     ; 101000000 + 100000 set a bit that was previously 0
6     101100000000000
7     101100010000000     ; increasing amounts of trailing zero around the bit being flipped by ADD
```

**Peeling the first 3 iterations would enable the BTS optimization,** where you just set the bit instead of actually creating `2^n` and adding.

Instead of *just* peeling them, we can just hard-code the starting point for `i=3` for larger n, and optimize the code that figures out a return value for the `n<3` case.  I came up with a branchless formula for that based on right-shifting the `0b1100` bit-pattern by 3, 2, or 0.

**Also note that for n>=18, the last shift count is strictly greater than half the width of the register, and the 2^i from odd `i` has no low bits**.  So only the last 1 or 2 iterations can affect the result.  It boils down to either `1<<n` for odd `n`, or `0` for even `n`.  This simplifies to `(n&1) << n`.

For `n=14..17`, there are at most 2 bits set.  Starting with result=0 and doing the last 3 or 4 iterations should be enough to get the correct total.  In fact, for any `n`, we only need to do the last `k` iterations, where `k` is enough that the total shift count from even `i` is >= 32.  Any bits set by earlier iterations are shifted out.  (I didn't add a branch for this special case.)

```
;; UNTESTED
;; special cases for n<3, and for n>=18
;; enabling an optimization in the main loop (BTS instead of add)
;; funky overflow behaviour for n>31: large odd n gives 1<<(n%32) instead of 0
power_optimized proc
     ; fastcall calling convention: arg: ECX = unsigned int n <= 31
     ; clobbers: ECX, EDX
     ; returns: EAX

    mov   eax, 14h      ; 0b10100 = power(3)
    cmp   ecx, 3
    ja    n_gt_3        ; goto main loop or fall through to hard-coded low n
    je    early_ret
    ;; n=0, 1, or 2  =>  1, 3, 12  (0b1, 0b11, 0b1100)

    mov   eax, 0ch      ; 0b1100  to be right-shifted by 3, 2, or 0
    cmp   ecx, 1        ; count=0,1,2 => CF,ZF,neither flag set
    setbe cl            ; count=0,1,2 => cl=1,1,0
    adc   cl, cl        ;                   3,2,0  (cl = cl+cl + (count<1) )
    shr   eax, cl
early_ret:
    ret

large_n:                ; odd n: result = 1<<n.  even n: result = 0
    mov   eax, ecx
    and   eax, 1        ; n&1
    shl   eax, cl       ; n>31 will wrap the shift count so this "fails"
    ret                 ; if you need to return 0 for all n>31, add another check

n_gt_3:
    ;; eax = running total for i=3 already
    cmp   ecx, 18
    jae   large_n

    mov   edx, ecx      ; EDX = n
    mov   ecx, 4        ; ECX = i=4..n loop counter and shift count

loop1:                  ; do{   // unrolled by 2
    ; multiply by 2^even power
    shl   eax, cl       ; total <<= i;  // same as total *= (1<<i)

    inc   edx
    cmp   ecx, edx
    jae   done            ; if (++i >= n) break;

    ; add 2^odd power.  i>3 so it won't already be set (thus no carry)
    bts   eax, edx      ; total |= 1<<i;

    inc   ecx           ; ++i
    cmp   ecx, edx
    jb    loop1         ; }while(i<n);

done:
    ret
```

By using BTS to set a bit in EAX avoids needing an extra scratch register to construct `1<<i` in, so we don't have to save/restore EBX.  So that's a minor bonus saving.

Notice that this time the main loop is entered with `i=4`, which is even, instead of `i=1`.  So I swapped the add vs. shift.

I still didn't get around to pulling the `cmp`/`jae` out of the middle of the loop.  Something like `lea edx, [ecx-2]` instead of `mov` would set the loop-exit condition, but would require a check to not run the loop at all for i=4 or 5.  For large-count throughput, many CPUs can sustain 1 taken + 1 not-taken branch every 2 clocks, not creating a worse bottleneck than the loop-carried dep chains (through `eax` and `ecx`).  But branch-prediction will be different, and it uses more branch-order-buffer entries to record more possible roll-back / fast-recovery points.